# Norwegian characters not rendering in a Quarto Book

Tags: html, r, rstudio, quarto

I am trying to render a Quarto book from RStudio and the Norwegian letters (Å,å,Ø,ø, Æ,æ) do not render correctly. The book is [here](https://ninanor.github.io/Dragehode/). Does anyone have any ideas how to make the letters render correctly (all the text in the book will eventually be written in Norwegian).

In the [-quarto.yml](https://github.com/NINAnor/Dragehode/blob/main/_quarto.yml) I have put "lang: no" and my locale is set to Norwegian Bokmål.

Comment: Do you have the correct character type? probably utf-8 doesn't include Norwegian letters, you should try to look at some iso types

Comment: A single � where you would expect a non-ASCII character is usually a giveaway that a character from an 8-bit charset (like ISO 8859) is being interpreted as UTF-8 (which fails).